# How can I start and stop a background task on travis?

Tags: shell, travis-ci

I need to start and restart a custom web server on travis. Starting in background is fine using a sub-shell (`.travis.yml`):

```
- if [ "$TEST_ADAPTER" = "HTTP" ]; then (vendor/bin/httpd.php start &); fi
```

To stop/kill the process again I'm trying to get its PID and then kill it:

```
- if [ "$TEST_ADAPTER" = "HTTP" ]; then (vendor/bin/httpd.php start &) && SERVER_PID=$!; fi
- ...
- if [ "$TEST_ADAPTER" = "HTTP" ]; then kill -9 $SERVER_PID && ...; fi
```

However, `SERVER_PID` is empty.

What is the right way to obtain the PID of a background process on travis in order to stop it (complication: without using an additional shell script)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
if [ "$TEST_ADAPTER" = "HTTP" ]; then
    vendor/bin/httpd.php&
    SERVER_PID=$!
fi
```

The `()` surrounding the command, creates a sub-shell. The `$!` comes empty in your examples, because the program is running in the sub-shell, but your `$!` is running on the parent shell.

Comment: As far as I know I can't write multi-lien statements in travis.yml https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/travis-ci/uaAP9zEdiCg

Comment: Right, but you can put the above in a shell script, and run that script from your .travis.yml file.

Comment: You can write multi-line statements in Travis CI YAML using the `|` multiline operator, see: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/bash-logic-structures-and-conditionals-if-case-loops-etc-travis-ci

Answer (score 9):

Answering question here as @xmonk's answer is correct in terms of functionality but requires an external shell script which- in turn- would need to use a temp file to write the pid value to.

I've just found out that travis-ci does actually allow multi-line statements which simplified the whole thing. Put this in `.travis.yml`:

```
- |
  if [ "$TEST_ADAPTER" = "HTTP" ]; then
    vendor/bin/httpd.php&
    SERVER_PID=$!
  fi
```

Comment: After this, you can use `- kill $SERVER_PID` in a separate step. The variable `$SERVER_PID` will be preserved across steps.