# Store output of very long command in a variable multiline in bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I can do this

```
- var=`<some command>`
```

but the command I want is too long and contains pipes so I would like to write it on separate lines like this:

```
- var=`<command>

  -arg1 value1

  -arg2 value2

 | awk '{print $2}' ...

`
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing? Does the bitbucket-pipelines.yaml editor give you an error message or do you get an error actually running the command? Could you post the whole step definition thats causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

### Multi-line YML commands

The YML syntax supports steps that have multiple lines. Just start the step with `"- |"` and indent it 2 columns further. See example from here: [How can I start and stop a background task on travis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800968/how-can-i-start-and-stop-a-background-task-on-travis)

```sh
- |
  # This is a comment in the multi-line block
  if [ "$TEST_ADAPTER" = "HTTP" ]; then
    vendor/bin/httpd.php&
    SERVER_PID=$!

  # Blank lines are also supported
  fi
```

### Call a bash script from YML

You can also call an external shell script from the YML file. This script can contain multiple lines:

```sh
- chmod +x my_script.sh # Make the script executable, if necessary
- ./my_script.sh # Run the external script
- bash ./my_script.sh # Run the external script
```

### Wrap long lines in shell scripts or YML commands

Both YML and shell scripts support wrapping long lines with the backslash `"\"` character at the end of the line. They are called bash continuation lines, and described here [Bash continuation lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316107/bash-continuation-lines) . Here's an example:

```sh
printf '%s' \
    "This will all be printed on a " \
    "single line (because the format string " \
    "doesn't specify any newline)"
```